# Multiple headers in 3 columns along with text beneath it

Tags: html, css, layout

The below image shows what I want to see on the page using HTML & CSS.

[image: Page layout]

Comment: I sometimes see a picture of ice cream and i want that ice cream but it involves me going out and buying it. Try doing the same, search anything usefull on google and come back with your code if you still have problems with it

Comment: Floats, table cells, inline-blocks, flexbox, grids. Take your pick.

Comment: Please put some code to show what you have done and where you have stuck at.Nobody can answer by just providing a hint of image.

Comment: Ok never mind. I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 div and give it a class name of your choice("myDiv"). Then in css set the "display" property to "inline block". Continue to put your desired content in each div.